# Front end post delete error confirmation and success message

Tags: posts, javascript

I am allowing Authors to delete their posts on the front end as they cant access the admin. I have this working, but what bothers me is the standard javascript onclick alert message - is there are way to style a js alert? From my understanding, no. Or to use jQuery for the message and use a modal window that I can style?

Also, after deletion the user is returned to the same page which is good, but there is no confirmation message - I'd like to have a message saying "Post successfully deleted". I just think these touches would provide a better user experience. Here's the code I am using:

```
function wp_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete This', $before = '', $after = '') {
global $post;
if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post->ID ) )
  return;
} else {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) )
  return;
}
$message = "Are you sure you want to delete ".get_the_title($post->ID)." ?";
$delLink = wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
$htmllink = "<a href='" . $delLink . "' onclick = \"if ( confirm('".$message."' ) ) { execute(); return true; } return false;\"/>".$link."</a>";
echo $before . $htmllink . $after;
$redirect = add_query_arg( 'success', 'true', $redirect );
}

<?php wp_delete_post_link('Delete your Entry', '<p><em>Delete your Entry: </em>', '</p>'); ?>
```

And was added to the author.php where the post delete button is

```
 <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['success'] ) ) {
                            echo 'Wahey!';
                            }
                        ?>
```

Comment: PS: the deleting is done on the front end by a user with the role of Author and they do not have access to wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here. For styling alerts/modals, that's a generic HTML/CSS question - [check out these](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/) to get you started.

For the second, it depends what you're doing after the delete - are you redirecting back to the frontend, or staying in the admin? (I will update my answer following your response).

You shouldn't be reinventing the wheel - use the core function [`get_delete_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_delete_post_link) to get the delete URL. This will handle nonces and any future changes to core, if and when they occur.

**Update:** For your redirect, add a param that you can then check for on page load:

```
$redirect = add_query_arg( 'success', 'true', $redirect );
```

And then in your template file:

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['success'] ) ) {
    echo 'Wahey!';
}
```

Comment: Ok so I dont have to use the standard js alert - I can use jquery for example to do this? For the second part I am just redirecting back to the same page and would like to show a confirmation message.

Comment: When you redirect back, add a query argument - see revision.

Comment: I added the redirect - see updated code above and added the if ( ! empty statement in my template at the top but nothing happens after deletion. The page reloads but nothing is there - maybe that's the issue as the page is reloading.

Comment: Update your question with the code you're using to redirect.

Comment: Ive added the last piece of your code above. This is in author.php